# Test custom Object in Rust

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to test my custom implementation of a linked list in Rust. the structure of the project is the one in the picture
[image]

now i've used `pub mod linked_list {...}` in order to export it and then import in tests/linked_list with `use linked_list::LinkedList` to write my tests and use my custom LinkedList object. when i run `cargo test` i got the error

```
let mut list = LinkedList::new();
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `LinkedList`
```

i don't get how to correctly import my module given the previous project schema. do i need to insert somthing in main.rs too?

Answer (score 1):

If `linked_list.rs` is in the `data_structures` directory, then you have to create `src/data_structures.rs` (alternatively, the old way was to name this file `src/data_structures/mod.rs`) with `pub mod linked_list;`.
For this to be usable in integration tests (`tests/linked_list.rs`), your crate must be a library.
Add `src/lib.rs` with `pub mod data_structures;`.
Then in `tests/linked_list.rs` add `use MY_CRATE::data_structures::linked_list::LinkedList` (where `MY_CRATE` is the name of your crate according to `Cargo.toml`).

Since your crate is now a library, you should adjust `src/main.rs` with `use MY_CRATE::data_structures::linked_list::LinkedList` also and remove `pub mod ...` (the modules are parts of the library now).

You might be interested in [this chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html) and [this one](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html?highlight=tests#integration-tests).